# Neo4j 2.0 Return Node, Node ID, and Node Labels from Server Plugin

Tags: neo4j

I have a server plug-in that does a query and returns a list of nodes (Iterable < Node > ).  I need to return the nodeID and labels of the noded as well so I get the same information (Preferably JSON) that I would get if I did a match clause like this:

```
Match (n) return n, ID(n), labels(n)
```

I know the server plug-in is limited in what types it can return.  Can this be done by returning a Representation object?  Or do I have to do an un-managed extension?  I found a couple obscure examples of a representation object, but it's unclear how to use it.

The documentation on un-managed extension has a performance warning, if I have to convert my server plug-in to an un-managed extension, am I going to have to add something to prevent performance degradation?  What is it about managed extensions that make them safer?

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (return-type, server, plugins, representation) will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: OK.  I'll take a look at some other questions to get a better idea about appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write a representation object that returns exactly what you want to return.

There is also MapRepresentation that you could extend to fit your purpose. Perhaps look at the source code of Node-Representation (and ignore all the exploratory URLs)

If that doesn't work, just return a list of maps, that should (I think) work.